# HTML table format with javascript style-change

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In my HTML table I would like to hide a question and show this if a specific option is chosen in the dropdown. This works fine with the code below, but the table isn't formatted right (two `<td>` in the space of one)?

Demo (pick "Other type" at "Type")
How to fix this?

```js
function setForm(value) {
  if (value == '99') {
    document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:block;';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:none;';
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>First question:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type: </td>
      <td>
        <select id="type" name="type" onchange="setForm(this.value)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="99">Other type</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="form1" style="display:none;">
      <td>Specify type:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="othertype" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="description" minlength="10" maxlength="1000" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `block` to display `tr` `table` element, just set `style display` to empty:

```
.style.display = '';
```

```js
function setForm(value) {
  if (value == '99') {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>First question:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type: </td>
      <td>
        <select id="type" name="type" onchange="setForm(this.value)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="99">Other type</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="form1"  style="display:none;">
      <td>Specify type:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="othertype" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="description" minlength="10" maxlength="1000" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `display:block` for a tr element. 
Try this:

```js
function setForm(value) {
  if (value == '99') {
    document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:table-row;';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:none;';
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>First question:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type: </td>
      <td>
        <select id="type" name="type" onchange="setForm(this.value)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="99">Other type</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="form1" style="display:none;">
      <td>Specify type:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="othertype" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="description" minlength="10" maxlength="1000" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
</form>
```